# Unable to start Apache on CentOS SSL Issue

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, ssl, private-key, pki

I am unable to start Apache on a CentOS Server with SELinux. The error log gives.

```
[root@server httpd]# cat test-error_log
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] Init: Private key not found
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218640442 error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 67710980 error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
```

It fails here also

```
[root@server private]#  openssl rsa -in test.key -check -noout
unable to load Private Key
140598241089352:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
140598241089352:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=RSA
140598241089352:error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib:rsa_ameth.c:115:
140598241089352:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
140598241089352:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
140598241089352:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:pem_pkey.c:132:
```

The path is in the conf file

```
[root@server conf]# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/test.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@server.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test
ServerName server.server.com

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/test.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/test.key


ErrorLog logs/test-error_log
CustomLog logs/test-access_log common
```

I also checked there are no spaces in the Private Key. Any other ideas where this is going wrong?

Also

```
[root@server etc]#  ls -dZ /etc/pki/tls/private/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /etc/pki/tls/private/
[root@server etc]#  ls -dZ /etc/pki/tls/certs/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /etc/pki/tls/certs/
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all navigate to the private key location . Open the test.key file using notepad or VI and check if it has the following format.

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Encrypted Data

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

if the above is not available , then the key is not in a correct format suitable for Apache.

if the private key is mismatching or not in correct format , then you have to generate a CSR and Private key once again a get the certificate reissued by the CA.

Comment: Private key is in that format. And no spaces. Already checked. In the end I just generated a new key. It began working.